# how to extract a method from jQuery UI library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, customization

how can i extract a method from jQuery UI library and add that to jquery library.

I only need some functionality from jQuery UI library ,like dragabble and droppable . I don't want to put the entire UI library for only this method.

Comment: go to http://jqueryui.com/download/ and then select only the functionality you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

download from here ------>> [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=00000000000000000000000000000000000)

1. Open the above link
2. Check the options you want to include (eg `dragabble` and `droppable`)
3. Select Theme or make your custom theme
4. Click on Download.

This will download your custom `jQuery UI`

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but can i add those functionality into jQuery library instead of adding one more js file for jqueryUI. I mean can we add that draggable method codes into main jQuery library ?

Comment: @Arun.Ds9r no it's not possible but you can decrease the size of `jQuery UI` file but above answer